# Can you do group by as map reduce in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

I have two collections. "`people`" are connected with a "`location`" like so:

```
location_id = ObjectId()

db.people.insert(
{
  _id : ObjectId(),
  name : "Nick",
  location : location_id
});

db.locations.insert(
{
 _id : location_id,
  city : "Cape Town"
});
```

I would like to create a histogram of `locations` giving the count of people in each `city`. But I can't seem to do it with the Mongo `group` command because they are different collections. Is the correct way to do it with map/reduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

map-reduce also won't help you here. It also operates on a single collection.

It seems to me that you're trying to apply your relational design skills here. Don't do that. MongoDB requires a fresh approach.

If I were you, I'd probably denormalize location into people collection.

```
db.people.insert(
{
  _id : ObjectId(),
  name : "Nick",
  location : {city: "Cape Town"}
});
```

This way it's possible to analyze this data with map-reduce, because everything is in the same collection.

Comment: There is a lot of information in the location collection though - not just city. Is there another way to do things without storing all of this in each person?

Comment: @nickponline: Use a relational database, for example :)

Comment: Is there an efficient way to denormalize the data without fetching the corresponding location for each person and updating?